# Is there a way to turn the sorting in a descending way on the y axis in Plotly?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, data-visualization, plotly.graph-objects

I've created a program which sorts the highest 50 US airports with the most starts in year 2015 in a bar chart. Unfortunately, the program shows them in an ascending order with the lowest on top.

[image: See image to see the problem]

Do you know a way how to turn them around? The data comes from a raw data set with even more US airports.

Comment: Try this: `fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")`